# pandas - convert column to minutes values

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to 'clean' a dataset which has a column called 'Duration'. It has elements like this:

```
18 mins
34 mins
1 hr 51 mins
1 day 1 hr 
1 day 2 hrs 32 mins
3 days 4 hrs 48 mins
```

In other words, most entries are numerical values (minutes) but some have text data that represent day/hr text. I'd like to covert them all to minutes

How do I achieve this in panda? Ideally I'd like to use some library/function that avoids my having to tokenize the string and manually parse/convert.

so far, I've been trying

```
data['Duration'] = pd.Timedelta(data['Duration'])
```

but I'm getting a

> ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta
>   or convertible

error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [99]: pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'].replace(['mins','hr','hrs'],
                                                ['min','hour','hour'],
                                                regex=True))
Out[99]:
0   0 days 00:18:00
1   0 days 00:34:00
2   0 days 01:51:00
3   1 days 01:00:00
4   1 days 02:32:00
5   3 days 04:48:00
Name: x, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

PS you may want to make more replacements if you have more "unusual" abbreviations...

Comment: @user1361529, glad i could help :-)

Comment: Awesome! answer